# How do I populate a struct instance with match results when using envy?

Tags: struct, rust, match

I want to populate a mutable variable with the results of matching an environment variable:

```
struct Environment {
    some_env_variable_1: String,
    some_env_variable_2: String,
    some_env_variable_3: String,
    some_env_variable_4: String,
}

match envy::from_env::<Environment>() {
    Ok(environment) => println!("{:#?}", environment),
    Err(error) => panic!("{:#?})", error),
};

//where I'm stuck
let mut e = Environment {
    some_env_variable_1: // want this to be from match
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the envy method which does all the parsing and population for you. The problem is that you **throw away the result** — it's only available inside the `match`:

```
match envy::from_env::<Environment>() {
    Ok(environment) => println!("{:#?}", environment), // gone now
    Err(error) => panic!("{:#?})", error),
};
```

You need to not throw it away:

```
let environment = match envy::from_env::<Environment>() {
    Ok(environment) => {
        println!("{:#?}", environment);
        environment // Now the entire `match` evaluates to `environment` 
    }
    Err(error) => panic!("{:#?})", error),
};
```

Or, more idiomatically, just use `expect`:

```
let environment: Environment = envy::from_env()
    .expect("Couldn't parse environment");

println!("{:#?}", environment);
```

---

Complete example:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate envy;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Environment {
    username: String,
    port: u16,
}

fn main() {
    let mut environment: Environment = envy::from_env()
        .expect("Couldn't parse environment variables");

    println!("{:#?}", environment);
}
```

```
$ USERNAME=overflow PORT=8787 cargo run

Environment {
    username: "overflow",
    port: 8787
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't realize that it threw it away at the end of the line. I tried the less idiomatic one, but didn't block it so it still threw away I presume.

Comment: @Joe To be clear, it's not the `{}` that makes the difference between discarding or not, it's the `let environment =` before the `match` expression. `Ok(environment) => environment,` would have worked as well. (Assuming that's what you meant by "block it")

Comment: @trentcl I see. Yes, I noticed the braces and just realized that return values in rust are usually implicit with the last statement so I see you have ```environment``` after the ```Ok(environment) =>```. Thank you!